# Matlab to R For Loop Conversion

Tags: r, matlab, for-loop

I'm currently trying to convert MATLAB code to R and run a loop to find the derivative of an equation.

MATLAB:

```
for i=1:length(x)
    dx(i,:) = lorenz(0,x(i,:),sigma,beta,rho);
end
```

My attempted code in R:

```
parameters <- c(s = 10, r = 28, b = 8/3)
state <- c(X = -8, Y = 7, Z = 27)

lorenz <- function(t, state, parameters) {
    with(as.list(c(state, parameters)), {
        dX <- s * (Y - X)
        dY <- X * (r - Z) - Y
        dZ <- X * Y - b * Z
        list(c(dX, dY, dZ))
    })
}

times <- seq(0.001, 1, by = 0.001)

out <- ode(y = state, times = times, func = lorenz, parms = parameters)

dx <- NULL
for (i in 1:1000){
    dx[i,] <- lorenz(0,state[i,],parameters)
}
```

I keep receiving the error "Error in state[i, ] : incorrect number of dimensions", any idea why?

Comment: `state` is a vector. In R a vector has only "one" dimension, i.e. use `state[[i]]` to extract element i. However, even with this change the loop will break after the third iteration as state has only three elements, while your are looping over 1:1000.

Comment: ... perhaps you meant `out` instead of `state`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant out rather than state. I changed the code to out[[i]] and out[,i] but am now receiving the error "Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) : 
  object 'Y' not found "

Comment: Sorry. With `out` using `out[i,]` is fine as `out` is a matrix. (: But the code will still raise an error because you haven't initalized dx as a matrix and .. see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```r
library(deSolve)

parameters <- c(s = 10, r = 28, b = 8/3)
state <- c(X = -8, Y = 7, Z = 27)

lorenz <- function(t, state, parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)), {
    dX <- s * (Y - X)
    dY <- X * (r - Z) - Y
    dZ <- X * Y - b * Z
    list(c(dX, dY, dZ))
  })
}

times <- seq(0.001, 1, by = 0.001)

out <- ode(y = state, times = times, func = lorenz, parms = parameters)

# Set up matrix
dx <- matrix(NA, nrow = 1000, ncol = 3)
for (i in 1:1000){
  # lorenz returns a list with one element. To assign to dx you have extract the list element using [[1]]
  dx[i,] <- lorenz(0,out[i,],parameters)[[1]]
}
head(dx)
#>                 [,1]          [,2]         [,3]
#>    [1,] 150.00000000  -15.00000000 -128.0000000
#>    [2,] 148.35404862  -15.83440159 -126.4953894
#>    [3,] 146.71639504  -16.62054372 -125.0045611
#>    [4,] 145.08747674  -17.35986863 -123.5280889
#>    [5,] 143.46759235  -18.05374748 -122.0664153
#>    [6,] 141.85715318  -18.70357479 -120.6200236
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>